# Multi-Page form submitted to single row - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a current project which I am having some troubles with. It will be written in PHP / MySQL

It is a multiple page form (3 pages)

When the user clicks 'next page' (submit button) the data needs to be stored in the database and the next page needs to open where the same thing will happen (this data is also stored in the database when 'next page' is clicked and then again same thing for the final page. I know a way where all the data can be submitted on the final page but we don't want this. We need to capture each and every step whether they finish filling out the entire form or not.

My issue is, how do I ensure that all of the data gets inserted into the single same row (under the same auto-incremented ID)?

I don't have the most experience when it comes to PHP/MySQL so go easy on me ;)

Thanks heaps in advance :)

Comment: on the first insert start a session, and put the db row id in the session and use that on the next inserts

Answer (score 0):

**This is one way :**

On the first page, you need to put all the information that is needed by the database (primary/index keys). Then you can do your `INSERT INTO` the database.

Then, you can just get the id of the newly inserted row, with a `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE mandatory_information_is_same` using the mandatory information you have. Keep it in something like a `$_SESSION` variable, or an hidden field in the form (unsafe).

Then on each new page, you just have to do an `UPDATE my_table SET extra_information WHERE id=$_SESSION['row_id']`, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the form data in the session. Eg user enters detail and clicks next button, store the data in a session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['firstpage']['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$_SESSION['firstpage']['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$_SESSION['firstpage']['username'] = $_POST['username'];

//check if data for first page stored

if(!empty($_SESSION['firstpage'])){
    //redirect to second page
}else{
    //stay on first page
}
```

Do the same for second page.

for third page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['thirdpage']['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$_SESSION['thirdpage']['confirm_id'] = $_POST['confirm_id'];


//check if data for Third page stored

if(!empty($_SESSION['thirdpage'])){
    //do validation for first and second page 
    //insert all session data to DB with same auto increment id
}else{
    //stay on third page
}
```

The reason to use sessions is to preserve data and stored data can be used in future as well. The user can leave and continue later. Its your choice if you want to use `sessions` or `cookies` but they both do the nearly the same thing the only difference is session data is stored in the server and cookies are stored in the browser. There are so many validations that you can do on the third page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Avinesh, thanks very much! Though wouldn't that only store the variables on each page and not actually store them in the db in each and every page?

Comment: The data will be stored globally and you will insert the data into db only ones that is in your third page.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks but I am looking for a solution that inserts every single page into the db as it is done (page 1 complete, insert to db: page 2 complete, insert to db, etc.) but all using the same id. Is that possible?

Comment: Oh yes you can still use sessions, so at page 1 you insert into db, [get last inserted id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) and store it in the session as `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` and use this id stored in session(`$_SESSION['id']`) in other 2 pages. [php and last inserted id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), u can also use the example provided in this site.

Comment: excellent, i know exactly what you mean now :) - I thought this was the way it would be done just wanted to make sure :) - Thanks heaps!